# Changing component prop based on onBlur function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that I can change how it is rendered based on a prop (added a failed state, and based on whether it fails or not it turns red or stays the original color), the logic for whether failed is `true` or `false` is in the parent component.

I want to change the failed state, but only `onBlur` (without changing the child component). Is there a way to pass in an `onBlur` function that applies changes to a child prop?

I've tried a number of different things like:

Child component:

```html
<input 
  failed={failed}
  onBlur={onBlur}
/>
```

Parent component:

```
handleBlur(value) {
  this.props.failed = value;
}
```

In the render function:

```
onBlur={() => this.handleBlur(newValue)}
```

But it did not work for me.

Comment: `props` are immutable

Comment: that makes sense, how would you go about making such a change though?

Comment: You use component's `state` instead.

Comment: in the parent component u should do this instead `this.setState({failed: value})` and then pass `failed` from `state` down to the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are data that are passed from a parent to its children and are made available through `this.props` in the child component.

You maintain whatever prop your are passing to child component either in parent component's state or in redux/flux state (if you have global state management).

When `failed` is modified, a state change should be triggered on parent component, which in-turn will trigger a re-render inside child component.

**For example:**

In the following, we pass `failed` as a prop, and `onFailureUpdate` function as a callback trigger to child component from parent.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   failed: false
  }
 }

 onFailureUpdate = (value) => {
   this.setState({
    failed: value
   });
 }

 render() {
  return (<ChildComponent failed={this.state.failed} onFailureUpdate={this.onFailureUpdate} />)
 }
}
```

In child component, on blur, we are using the function we passed as prop to modify state in parent, which in-turn will re-render child component.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  onBlur = (e) => {
    this.props.onFailureUpdate(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        value={this.props.failed}
        onBlur={(e) => this.onBlur(e)}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**Other way:**

Or, if there's no necessity for props or parent-child relationship, you can eliminate the need for parent container and go for state maintenance in child.

```
class RewrittenChildComponentWithState extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
   this.state = {
    failed: false
   };
  }

  onBlur = (e) => {
    this.setState({
     failed: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        value={this.state.failed}
        onBlur={(e) => this.onBlur(e)}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your confusion.

Comment: I ended up just going down the path that I was trying to work around, and just created an action to toggle the amount, and passed it in through the state. Seemingly React Hooks offers a solution to this as well, but that wasn't feasible for me. Thanks everyone for all the help!